# Select Last movement for each ID in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a MS-Access table, and would like to have a query to result all the information on the last entry from a certain id.

My table (DEPOSIT_MOVEMENTS) is the following:

```
MOV_CODE | WORK | DEPOSIT_CODE | TYPE | DATE | DESTINATION
```

I am looking to obtain for each DEPOSIT_CODE the latest register (on date), and obtain the *MOV_CODE so that I can get the DESTINATION of the item.

DEPOSIT_CODE may have many MOV_CODE on different dates.

I have tried with different options posted on stackoveflow, but I coudl not get any of these to work properly.

Right now I am trying with the GROUP BY, but cannot get it working.

```
SELECT t1.[DEPOSIT_CODE], MAX(t1.[DATE]), t1.[MOV_CODE]
FROM [DEPOSIT_MOVEMENTS] AS t1 
GROUP BY t1.[DEPOSIT_CODE];
```

Any help or guidance is welcome.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT dm.*
FROM [DEPOSIT_MOVEMENTS] AS dm
WHERE dm.DATE = (SELECT MAX(dm2.DATE)
                 FROM [DEPOSIT_MOVEMENTS] AS dm2
                 WHERE dm2.DEPOSIT_CODE = dm.DEPOSIT_CODE
                );
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast and effective! I thought I had tried a similar solution previously with no success. But this one really works :) Thanks!